# Leaflet Draw how to hide click cancel tooltip

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip, leaflet-draw

I'm using Leaflet Draw to edit a map, but whenever I go into edit mode, I get a rather large tooltip attached to the mouse pointer (see screenshot), which obscures quite a bit of the map and prevents me from seeing my own marker tooltips when I hover over them.

I've searched the documentation to try to find what option switches it off, but cannot figure out which one to use.

Does anyone know which option switches off this tooltip?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've just how to do this. To switch off the tooltip, just set the following two options to an empty string:

```
L.drawLocal.edit.handlers.edit.tooltip.subtext = '';
L.drawLocal.edit.handlers.edit.tooltip.text    = '';
```

To see other things you can change that aren't documented very well, just look in the following source file:

node_modules/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js